# Call another python file in the backend

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I've installed "mod_wsgi" and I am experimenting with python on the backend. I have a php background, so I am struggling on making redirects on the backend to another python file, example:

This is my test.py, which is called when I go to "http://localhost/":

```
def application(environ, start_response):

    start_response("301 Redirect", [("Location", "http://localhost/test.py")])

    return [""]
```

And "test.py":

```
def application(environ, start_response):

    status = "200 OK"

    output = test()

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'), ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]


def test():

    return "ok"
```

I am not sure if it is correct to use "application" in "test.py".

In php I would redirect the user to another "*.php" file, do some processing and it would work fine, but I get this error when trying to do the above:

> The page isn't redirecting properly.
>   Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

I know I could frameworks like Django, but I want to this all by myself, so I can learn a bit more. So, how can I make those redirects just like I make them in PHP? What is the correct and most pythonic way to do redirects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike cgi/php, where your web server parses requests and dispatches them to corresponding script files, in the wsgi world you have one single python script that gets all requests and is responsible for parsing and dispatching. So when you redirect from `index.py` to `test.py`, you just invoke `index` once again, with `env[PATH_INFO]` equal to "test.py".

Regarding the overall structure, try not to think in terms of separate scripts, as you're used to in php. Just build your app, split it into functions and modules if it has to be, and check `PATH_INFO` in `application()` to dispatch a request to an appropriate function. For example, if your app deals with users, you might want to add a `user` module and invoke it like this:

```
 import user

 def application(environ, start_response):
      if environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/user/create':
            user.create()
      if environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/user/delete':
            user.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Now I know why I get that error from firefox, my script will keep calling "index.py" every single time. What I don't get is: how do I dispatch? You wrote that I must invoke "index" with "env[PATH_INFO]" equal to "test.py".  And after that? How do I call the "test.py" file to actually execute it? And do I really need an "application" method in "test.py"? Thanks.

Comment: @Falcon: answered in the post

Comment: Thank you! I thought I could do it just like in php instead of having to previously know all the structure of the application and "map" it inside "index.py" or "map" it while I create it.

Comment: @Falcon: right, application programming requires more prior consideration compared to the step-by-step cgi development, but ultimately you'll end up with a better designed system.